# where to put text file in war packing spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, text, position, war

I have a spring boot web project, and I have some kind of DB(data-base) in few text files(I don't want to use MongoDB or MySQL), and my whole project works, but once I pack it in war it says error 500 and that it cant find these text files that have crucial information.

Where do I need to put these text files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you are using Spring Boot, add this dependency and then load it to your boot app::

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-jar-resources</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>



public static void main(String[] args) {
        StandardEnvironment environment = new StandardEnvironment();
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .sources(SpringBootJarResourcesDemoApplication.class)
            .environment(environment)
            .resourceLoader(new JarResourceLoader(environment, "resources.extract.dir"))
            .build()
            .run(args);
    }
```

Comment: ok, I did that, and where should my text files be, since it shows error 500 again

Comment: Please go through this site which explains how exactly you can implement this library in your boot app.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt

Comment: this didnt help me, I still dont know where to put text files, and what are paths to them, if I want to access them in war app

Comment: Have you tried keeping those files inside the resource folder and accessing it from there? Let me build, test and provide you a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the program as promised :- Keep your file under src\main\resources\secretdbfile.txt

```
@SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner
    {
        final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
                 
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);
            app.run(args);
        }
     
        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception 
        {
        
            try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/secretdbfile.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
           String contents = reader.lines()
               .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
           System.out.println(contents);
       }
        }
    }
```